# Rococo Slot Request problem on adding file

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, rococo

When requesting Rococo slots [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Rococo&template=rococo.yaml), there are two options:

- Upload your Genesis Head (genesis state) - Do not submit a compressed
  file.
- Upload your Validation Code (genesis runtime Wasm) - Do not
  submit a compressed file.

I am confused what exactly should I need to upload there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the Substrate tutorial: [Connect a local parachain](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/) there is a section where it shows you how to export information about its runtime and genesis state: [Prepare the parachain collator](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/connect-a-local-parachain/#prepare-the-parachain-collator).

1- Export the WebAssembly runtime for the parachain.

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node export-genesis-wasm --chain your-chainspec.json name-of-your-wasm
```

2- And Generate a parachain genesis state.

```
./target/release/parachain-template-node export-genesis-state --chain your-chainspec.json name-of-your-genesis-state
```

What you have to upload in the issue for requesting Rococo slots are this 2 files you have just generated: `name-of-your-wasm` and `name-of-your-genesis-state`. Drag and drop the files exactly like that or you can copy the content of this files and paste there.
What means with the Do not submit a compressed file is basically to upload only the file and do not compressed it to avoid issues when retrieving the data.

Comment: what format should I make while creating file?

Comment: I just create file with name `para-4284-genesis-state` but I can't upload this file

Comment: What's the error? an easy trick is to convert this file to .txt (rename it) and you will be able to upload

Comment: thanks @Alex, how much time does it take to accept my request?

Comment: the time it depends, yours should be onboarding now